# Merging multiple datacolumns in .net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datarow, datacolumn

I am trying to merge multiple datacolumns in a datatable. Eg. The address data is stored in a different columns such as, Housename, street, city and postcode. I want to merge those datacolumns in to one and put it into one datacolumn as "Address".

Any suggestions while I do research?

Thank you

Comment: "Any suggestions while I do research?" You should research **before** you post here ;-)

Comment: You could use @Max approach or simply concatenate the fields in the sql-query, so that your DataTable automatically contains this column.

Answer (score 2):

Add a new datacolumn to the datatable, and use it's Expression property
( more info here  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx )

in the expression property uou can concatenate the value of other column like that

```
dim myNewDataColumn as new datacolumn
myNewDataColumn.Expression = "Address + ' ' + city + ' ' + state" 
mtDataTable.Column.Add(myNewDataColumn)
```

Where Address, City and State are other columns of the datatable